# Django checkbox form doesn't show up

Tags: python, django

First of all, sorry for the easy question, I'm new on Django and the divine doc hasn't helped me.

The fact is, I'm trying to display a checkbox form on a template but despite having followed django's doc to the letter, it refuses to appear.

Here is my code:

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import SoinsSelect
    
class SoinsSelectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SoinsSelect
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
    
class SoinsSelect(models.Model):
    blabla = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**views.py**

```
    from soins.forms import SoinsSelectForm
    from django.shortcuts import render
    
        def CreateSoinsSelect(request):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = SoinsSelectForm(request.POST or None)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
            else:
                form = SoinsSelectForm()
            return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
```

**profile.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    {% load static %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/profile.css"%}">

</head>
<body>

  <div class="nav-right visible-xs">
  <div class="button" id="btn">
    <div class="bar top"></div>
    <div class="bar middle"></div>
    <div class="bar bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- nav-right -->
<main>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-right hidden-xs">
      <div class="button" id="btn">
        <div class="bar top"></div>
        <div class="bar middle"></div>
        <div class="bar bottom"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- nav-right -->
  </nav>

  <a href="https://codepen.io/tonkec/" class="ua" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </a>

      <section>
    <article>
       <h4>Hello {{ user.forename }}</h4>
        <p>Here is you data :</p>
        <p>Username : {{ user.forename }}</p>
        <p>name : {{ user.name }}</p>
        <p>email : {{ user }}</p>
        <p>N° de téléphone : {{ user.phone }}</p>
        <p>Adresse : {{ user.adress1 }}  {{ user.adress2 }}</p>
        <p>Date de naissance : {{ user.dateNaiss }}</p>
        <p>Mes points de fidelité : {{ user.fidelity }}</p>
        <br>
        <button type="submit"> <a href="{% url 'users:edit_profile' %}" class="nav-link">Changer mes informations</a></button>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section>
    <article>
      <h4>Faites votre réservation</h4>
        <form action="#" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section>
    <article>
      <h4>Section 3</h4>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section>
    <article>
      <h4>Section 4</h4>
    </article>
  </section>

</main>

<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="sidebar-list">
      <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="{% url 'Accueil' %}" class="sidebar-anchor">Accueil</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor" data-rel="1" class="active">Mon compte</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor" data-rel="2">Réserver un soin</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor" data-rel="3">Mes réservations</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor" data-rel="4">Mon historique</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="{% static "js/profile.js" %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: The views.py and profile.html are in a another app but i don't think that's a problem since I imported it ?

PS2: I have a function in profile.js that hide < section > depending on the < li > in which I'm, but I don't think it's a problem since the submit button which is in the form appear.

PS3: Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

look up you error details to know if any error was raised. in your views.py, if the views.py and forms.py are in same app or folder, import SoinsSelectForm like this `from .forms import SoinsSelectForm` and for your
**forms.py** it should be like this

```
from .models import SoinsSelect
    
class SoinsSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SoinsSelect
        fields = '__all__'
```

hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't solve my problem. The view.py and the profile.html are in the same app when the models.py and the forms.py are in the same other app. I'm calling them correctly so the problem is elsewhere. I don't get any error, all I can get is that : <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="j3ptUgq6cG4Jy0tOduot6S86iheFbhrEFTzMJvnKLLFGRdj713ja5C6fyoEDDIAW"> when I check the tag on the console of the navigator. I don't understant why type parameter is hidden.